# NSTimer - Invalid operand to binary % error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer

I'm trying to update a UILabel with the amount of time left on an audio track in minutes and seconds. I'm getting an *Invalid operand to binary % error* . Here's the code:

```
 - (void)updateTimeLeft
{
        NSTimeInterval timeLeft = self.player.duration - self.player.currentTime;

        int min = timeLeft / 60;

        int sec = timeLeft % 60;

        self.timeDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d : %d", min,sec];
}
```

I changed the code to the following:

```
int sec = lroundf(timeLeft) % 60;
```

The error goes away, but I suspect that there's a problem here because the timer counts down correctly from 5:00 to 4:10, but then displays 4:9 instead of 4:09

thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alterations below,

```
self.timeDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", min,sec];
```